# RecyclerView.LayoutManager doesn't show view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I decided to play around with custom `LayoutManager` for my `RecyclerView`. Unfortunately when I set it to `RecyclerView` nothing appear. Only when I replace it with the `LinearLayoutManager` all views show up.

Here is my `LayoutManager`:

```
 public class MyLayoutManager extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager{

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(0);
        addView(view);
        measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0);
        layoutDecorated(view, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Please give me a hint how to implement `LayoutManager` properly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt that the best way is to read the source code of  **LinearLayoutManager** or **GridLayoutManager**

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutManager` - Helps in positioning the items in `RecyclerView`

[image]

A `RecyclerView` needs to have a layout manager and an adapter to be instantiated. A layout manager positions item views inside a `RecyclerView` and determines when to reuse item views that are no longer visible to the user.

`RecyclerView` provides these built-in layout managers:

1. `LinearLayoutManager` shows items in a vertical or horizontal scrolling list.
2. `GridLayoutManager` shows items in a grid.
3. `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` shows items in a staggered grid.

To create a custom layout manager, extend the [`RecyclerView.LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) class.

Here is a good [example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)
```

check your recyclerview version，

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue when trying to create a custom layout manager for RecyclerView. A video that I found that was useful and very underrated was a talk by [Polly McEldowney](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W55PSgzH6HI&t=122s) .

In my case, the RecyclerView's layout height and width were both set to match_parent.

Polly's video does a really good job of breaking down the problem into small discrete steps.